# How to create jQuery Datatable Drill-down rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

In my MVC project, I am trying to use a single `Datatable` and collapse the rows for detail data as shown on [Creating an expandable master-details table (jQuery DataTables and ASP.NET MVC integration - Part IV)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189621/Creating-an-expandable-master-details-table-jQuery). On the other hand, I am looking for a similar examples of `jQuery Datatable` `master-detail` relations for `ASP.NET MVC`, but unfortunately I have not another suitable sample or tutorial from at least 50 pages on the web. Is there a similar examples like [that](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189621/Creating-an-expandable-master-details-table-jQuery)? Thanks in advance...

Comment: **Does anybody else who used jQuery DataTable ever before???**

Comment: You have to break down your problems into smaller manageable pieces. In your answer you are asking for an entire sample solution / tutorial. Nobody has the time to help you with that. You should post what code you have and tell us what error message you are getting. Your question should specifically about how to deal with that error. Perhaps you will need to ask a couple questions to get all the information you need to get your drill-down rows.

Comment: @RafaelCichocki Thanks, I know. But I do not want anybody else to write the entire tutorial at here, **just an advice about the suitable source for using jQuery Datatable Drill-down rows**. So, if someone else have done such a kind of usage ever before, it is not too hard for them to give just an advice for sample of this usage.

Comment: @RafaelCichocki There must be many people who have used jQuery Datatable Drill-down rows in their project and they can give an example post of page about the usage of it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did similar work for one of the projects. I had one collapse/expand button that works for the whole table and each row has its one collapse expand icon. here is my code.

Note: I have renamed the variables to hide my data so the code might not work as it is.

```
function populateInstanceTable(tableData){
    // Use to determine whether the child rows for all parents should be shown or hidden.
    var SHOW_ALL_CHILDREN_FLAG = false;
    var CHILD_DISPLAY_STATE_OVERRIDE = false;
    var TABLE = $('#table_instance').DataTable(
                                                {
                                                    'aaData': tableData,
                                                    'bProcessing': true,
                                                    'aoColumns': [
                                                                    {
                                                                        'sTitle': 'Column1',
                                                                        'mData' : 'col1Data'
                                                                    }, 
                                                                    {
                                                                        'sTitle': 'Column2',
                                                                        'mData' : 'col2Data'
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                        'sTitle': 'Column3',
                                                                        'mData': 'col3Data'
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                        'class': 'show-details',
                                                                        'orderable': false,
                                                                        'data': null,
                                                                        'defaultContent': ''
                                                                    }
                                                                ]
                                                }
                                            );
    function getDetailContent(details) {
        return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
               '<tr>' +
                    '<td style="border:0px;">More Details:</td>'+
                    '<td style="text-align:left;max-width:100%;border:0px;">' + details + '</td>' +
               '</tr>' +
               '</table>';
    }

    //This function shows and hides multiple child rows with details, for following conditions
    // when user clicks '+' or '-' icon
    // When user uses search
    // when user changes the number of entries per page
    // when user navigates through the table
    // @remark: With exception of expand all and collapse all events, the display state is retained for child rows 
    //that have been previously visited. Visited implies the parent row's show or hide details icon was individually clicked.
    function collapseOrExpandRows() {
        var numberOfVisibleParentRows = $('#table_instance tbody tr td.show-details').length;
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfVisibleParentRows; i++) {            
        var parentJQRow = $('.show-details').parents('tr').eq(i);
            var parentDTRow = TABLE.row(parentJQRow);
            // visited_child helps us retain the state of the child row display while 
            // searching, navigating, sorting or changing number of entries
            // We always change the state of child if collapse all(- icon) or expand all(+ icon) is clicked.
            if (parentJQRow.hasClass('visited_child') === false  || CHILD_DISPLAY_STATE_OVERRIDE === true) {
                if (SHOW_ALL_CHILDREN_FLAG === true) {

                    // We are populating a child row with a table because the parent datatable does not support colspan property.
                    parentDTRow.child(getDetailContent(parentDTRow.data().details)).show();
                    parentJQRow.addClass('shown');
                } 
                else {
                    parentDTRow.child.hide();
                    parentJQRow.removeClass('shown');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //To display details, this event handler shows or hides a single child row 
    //when the show-details cell is clicked on the parent row
    $('#table_instance tbody').on('click', 'td.show-details', function() {
        var parentJQRow = $(this).parents('tr'); 
        var parentDTRow = TABLE.row(parentJQRow);

        //visited_child helps us retain the state of the child row display while 
        // searching, navigating, sorting or changing number of entries
        parentJQRow.addClass('visited_child');

        if (parentDTRow.child.isShown()) {
            parentDTRow.child.hide();
            parentJQRow.removeClass('shown');
        } 
        else {
            parentDTRow.child(getDetailContent(parentDTRow.data().details)).show();
            parentJQRow.addClass('shown');
        }

        CHILD_DISPLAY_STATE_OVERRIDE = false;
    });

    // This event handler retains the state of the child row display 
    // when navigating through the table.
    $('.dataTables_paginate').on('click', function() {
        collapseOrExpandRows();
    });

    // This event handler hides child row for all visible parents.
    $('.collapseall').on('click', function() {
        CHILD_DISPLAY_STATE_OVERRIDE = true;
        SHOW_ALL_CHILDREN_FLAG = false;
        collapseOrExpandRows();
    });

    // This event handler shows child row of all visible parents. 
    $('.expandall').on('click', function() {
        CHILD_DISPLAY_STATE_OVERRIDE = true;
        SHOW_ALL_CHILDREN_FLAG = true;
        collapseOrExpandRows();
    });

    // This event handler retains the state of the child row display 
    // when the user selects the number of entries to display in the table
    $('div.dataTables_length select').on('change', function() {
        collapseOrExpandRows();
    });

    // This event handler retains the state of the child row display 
    // when the user clicks on header to sort
    $('thead > tr > th', '#table_instance').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('show-details') === false) {
            collapseOrExpandRows();
        }
    });

    // This event handler retains the state of the child row display 
    // when the user searches
    $('div.dataTables_filter input').keyup(function() {
        collapseOrExpandRows();
    });
}
```

I have attached the screenshot for your help.
[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your reply and useful post. As far I I understood, the expand/collapse can be done only one button and it is not possible to expand/collapse a row individually. Is that true? If so, it is not suitable for me, but anyway, as it is a useful code, voted+ :)

Comment: so there are two functionalities, There is one button that do expand/collapse for all the rows also each row has its own expand/collapse icon.  This function does indivdual expand/collapse      `$('#table_instance tbody').on('click', 'td.show-details', function()`

Comment: Any ide about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571553/jquery-datatable-individual-column-searching-on-table-header) question?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example on [Datatables Blog](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-10-02) having also a wonderful sliding property. There is unfortunately not so much example on the web regarding to this issue, but I hope this example is useful for you.

Comment: Perfect!.. It works like a charm and it is much more easier to integrate to the project. Many thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread. But I could not find any good examples since then. I created a working example which is fully scalable using jQuery (3.5.0) and Datatables (1.10.19). Table, columns, rows and sub tables are created on the fly based on data structure.

You can find the demo and code here - https://banglaonline.org/dashboard/temp/dt.html. The js code is in https://banglaonline.org/dashboard/temp/dt.js.

function dataStructure() - creates the first table

```
function dataStructure(){
    $("#content_structure").html("<div id='content_structure_table' style='width:80%'></div>");
    var groupBy=[fieldOrder[0].field];//level 1 order
    var dtTextColumnIndex=[];
    var dtNumColumnIndex=[];
    var colCount=1;
    var valuefunction=null;//dataCreateValueFunctions();

    tblFormatParam = formatTblDataStructure('tblDataStructure',0,"1=1");
    html = tblFormatParam[0];
    tableDef = tblFormatParam[1];

    $("#content_structure_table").html(html);   
    var table = $('#tblDataStructure').DataTable(tableDef);
    //drill down event
    $('#tblDataStructure tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){
        e=$(this);
        drillTblDataStructure(e,table,valuefunction);
    });

    $('#tblDataStructure' ).bind( 'xhr.dt', function () {
        var json = table.ajax.json();
        $('#tblDataStructure').unbind( 'xhr.dt');
        //structureChart(json.data);
    });

}
```

function drillTblDataStructure - controls the expansion and contraction of nested tables

```
function drillTblDataStructure(td,table,valuefunction) {
    //console.log("td clicked -"+td.attr("datavalue"));
    var tr = td.closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );   
    currentFieldOrder = parseInt(td.attr("fieldorder"));
    //close all other open rows
    tdDrillControls = document.querySelectorAll("td.details-control");
    for (var i=0;i<tdDrillControls.length;i++){
        tdi= $(tdDrillControls[i]);
        tri = tdi.closest("tr");
        r = table.row( tri);
        if (r.child.isShown() && (tdi.attr("datavalue") != td.attr("datavalue"))) {//second condition is importatnt, otherwise the row will be keep on showing

            r.child.hide();
            tri.removeClass('shown');
            tdi.html('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>')
        }
    }
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
        td.html('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>')
    }
    else {
        td.html('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minus"></span>')  
        childFieldOrder = currentFieldOrder +1;
        var whereClause = td.attr("whereClause")+" and "+td.attr("datacolumn")+" = '"+td.attr("datavalue")+"'"; 
        var childTableID = childFieldOrder*10+iTableCounter;
        tblFormatParam = formatTblDataStructure('tblDataStructure_' + childTableID,childFieldOrder,whereClause);
        html = tblFormatParam[0];
        tableDef = tblFormatParam[1];
        // Open this row
        row.child( html ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
        var oInnerTable = $('#tblDataStructure_' + childTableID).DataTable(tableDef);
        $('#tblDataStructure_' + childTableID).bind( 'xhr.dt', function () {//table data is loaded via ajax
            var json = oInnerTable.ajax.json();
            $('#tblDataStructure_' + childTableID).unbind( 'xhr.dt');                                   
        });
        $('#tblDataStructure_' + childTableID +' tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){
            e=$(this);
            drillTblDataStructure(e,oInnerTable,valuefunction);
        });
        iTableCounter++;
    }
}
```

function formatTblDataStructure - used by the above two functions to create table structure and definition for Datatables

```
function formatTblDataStructure ( table_id, groupOrder, whereClause) {
    var dtTextColumnIndex=[];
    var dtNumColumnIndex=[];
    var colCount=1;
    if(groupOrder<fieldOrder.length-1) //it is not the last item in the order
        var tdColumns=[
            {   className:      'details-control',
                orderable:      false,
                data:           null,
                defaultContent: '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus style="cursor:pointer;"></span>'
            }
        ];
    else
        var tdColumns=[
            {   className:      '',
                orderable:      false,
                data:           null,
                defaultContent: ''
            }
        ];
    tdColumns.push({data:fieldOrder[groupOrder].field});
    html="<table id='"+table_id+"' ><thead><tr><th></th>";
    thtml="<tr><td></td>";

    html+="<th>"+fieldOrder[groupOrder]["dataField"]+"</th>";
    thtml+="<td></td>"
    dtTextColumnIndex.push(colCount);
    colCount++;
    var valuefunction=[];

    for(f in valueFields){//getting field names from json column names
        html+="<th>"+valueFields[f]["dataField"]+"</th>";
        thtml+="<td></td>"
        dtNumColumnIndex.push(colCount);
        colCount++;
        txt = valueFields[f].groupFunction+"("+valueFields[f].field+") as `"+valueFields[f].field+"`";
        valuefunction.push(txt);
        tdColumns.push({data:valueFields[f].field});
    }
    html+="</tr></thead><tbody>"+thtml+"</tr></tbody></table>"; 
    groupBy=[fieldOrder[groupOrder].field]; 
    var tableDef={
        "ajax":{
            url: src,
            data:{
                request:'dataStructure'
                ,dbid:sessionID
                ,group:JSON.stringify(groupBy)
                ,where:whereClause
                ,value:JSON.stringify(valuefunction)
                ,dt:"assoc"
            }
        },
        createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
            $( row ).find('td:eq(0)').attr(
                {
                    'fieldOrder': groupOrder,
                    'datavalue': data[fieldOrder[groupOrder].field],
                    'datacolumn': fieldOrder[groupOrder].field,
                    'whereClause': whereClause
                }
            );
        },
        columns: tdColumns,
        columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: dtTextColumnIndex,
            className: 'dt-body-left dt-head-left'
        },
        {
            targets: dtNumColumnIndex,
            className: 'dt-body-right dt-head-right'
            //,"render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
            //  return infGroup.format(data);
            //}
        }
      ]
    }
    return [html,tableDef];
}
```

In the example, data is retrieved as json via ajax from a php backend. Example json response:

```
{

"data": [

{ "dash_uploaded_data_text1": "Dept 1", "dash_uploaded_data_numeric1": "3", "dash_uploaded_data_numeric2": "11" },

{ "dash_uploaded_data_text1": "Dept 4", "dash_uploaded_data_numeric1": "4", "dash_uploaded_data_numeric2": "8" }

]

}
```